# Trying to Generate the superior list of User in AD using Powershell

Tags: active-directory, ldap, powershell-3.0

This is a simple powershell script which takes user as input and generates user's hierarchy in the organization until top, not sure where i am going wrong, following is the code;

```
$Users = "XXXX"
function ManagedBy($User, $Root)
{
    $Search = [adsisearcher]$root
    $Search.filter = "((samaccountname=$user))"
    $UserAtt = $Search.Findone()
    $Title = $UserAtt.Properties.title
    $ManDN = $UserAtt.properties.manager

    if($title -match "avp")
    {
         $ManDN
         $Title
    }
    else
    {
         $ManRoot = "[ADSI]`"LDAP://" + $ManDN
         $ManDN = "`"" + $ManDN + "`""
         $ManSamID = dsquery user $ManDN -o samid
         $Managedby $ManSamID $ManRoot
    }
}

foreach($User in $Users)
{
    $UserDN = dsquery user -samid $user
    $UserCN = $UserDN.split("=")[1].split(",")[0]
    $UserDN = $USerDN.Substring(1)
    $root = "[ADSI]`"LDAP://" + $UserDN
    Managedby $User $Root
}
```

This is supposed to print AVP of the person but its failing with errors; what am i doing wrong? let me know if any questions. I am refraining to use any AD command-lets for the powershell to make it work universally. Please advice accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can first correct the typo in `ManagedBy` function and replace

```
$ManRoot = "[ADSI]`"LDSP://" + $ManDN
```

with

```
$ManRoot = "[ADSI]`"LDAP://" + $ManDN
```

Then you should give the error you met.

Comment: It was "LDAP", i typed in the whole thing , thats why the typo.Will collect the errors.